# Calculate monthly value between 2 tables without an explicit relationship in Power BI model

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a measure that calculates (a/qty)*100 for each month,
where qty commes from Delivery table (generated with an R script)

```
  month        qty
  <date>     <dbl>
1 2019-02-01     1
2 2019-03-01   162
3 2019-04-01  2142
4 2019-05-01   719
```

And **a** comes from a table TABLE_A that has been created within Power BI that looks like this :

```
Client     Date            a
x          2019-03-07      3
x          2019-04-14      7
y          2019-03-12      2
```

So far, I managed to calculate that value overall with the following measure formula :

```
MEASURE = CALCULATE( (Sum(TABLE_A[a])/sum(Delivery[qty]))*100)
```

The issue I have is that I would need this measure monthly (i.e. join the tables on month) without explicitly defining a link between the tables in the PowerBI model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each row in `TABLE_A` you need to look up the corresponding `qty` in `Delivery`, so try something along these lines:

```
MEASURE =
DIVIDE(
    SUM( TABLE_A[a] ),
    SUMX(
        TABLE_A,
        LOOKUPVALUE(
            Delivery[qty],
            Delivery[month], EOMONTH( TABLE_A[Date], -1 ) + 1
        )
    )
) * 100
```

The formula `EOMONTH( TABLE_A[Date], -1 )` returns the end of the previous month relative to that date and adding 1 day to that to get the start of the current month for that date.